# How to write a permutation function without generate all the permutation in ml?

Tags: algorithm, permutation, ml

I have to write to check whether a list is following a certain pattern. The list is looks like ((2 , 2), (2 , 1), (2 , 0), (1 , 1), (1 , 0) (0 ,0))........ it contains about 50 pair, so the total permutation can take lots and lots of space. And there is always have one permutation which matches the certain pattern. and I need to find this permutation.

I know that the basic idea about permutation is to generate all the possible ones and compare them with the pattern. Since it took too much space,is there a better way? I think to random rotate the list, but there will be repeat one, so it may take too much time. Is there any better way to this?

====update
the list is all possible tiles of a N-double domino set. if N is 1, the list is (0,0),(0,1). if N is 2, the list is (0 , 0) (0 , 1) (1 , 1) (1 , 2) (2 , 2) (2 , 0). And N=2 can have the match pattern, which is a loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you be able to provide your sample and code? In that way, you would be likely to receive more support. :)

Comment: @jazzurro the list is all possible tiles of a N-double domino set. if N   is 1, the list is (0,0),(0,1). if N is 2, the list is (0 , 0) (0 , 1) (1 , 1) (1 , 2) (2 , 2) (2 , 0). And N=2 can have the match pattern, which is a loop.

Comment: can you tell us more about the pattern? a permutation of all domino that create a loop? and how large is N?